# Magento - Check cart for product ID

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.8

In Magento CE 1.8.0.0 I am trying to perform the following:

```
if cart subtotal is equal to or greater than 99
and has product ID 691
    show this static block.
```

I know how to get the cart subtotal, I know how to show static blocks, I believe I can make the if statement work with multiple requirements with `&&`.

What I cannot figure out for the life of me, is how to check if a particular product ID is in the cart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$found = false;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProductId() == 691){
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The value of `$found` will tell you if the product is in the cart or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

if ($quote->hasProductId(691)) {
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach($items as $item)
        { 
           if ($item->getProductId()==691){
            /* Here, you can display any message or something else.*/
        }
      }
?>
```

Comment: Add some explanations to your answer.

Comment: You can match your product id with the above condition, If condition match then you can display any message or something else.

Comment: Please update your answer and add the explanation there.